# what is the solution to StringIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java

when i use s.charAt(0) while s is an string input from the user, I get this as an error even though the program runs the first half of the program.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0
>       at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:658)
>       at Shopping.main(Shopping.java:22)

What's the solution to this program? here is my code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Shopping {
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Programmed by Raymond Lee");
    System.out.println("Welcome to Shopper's Paradise");
    ShoppingCart cart = new ShoppingCart();
    System.out.print("Enter the name of the first item: ");
    String item = keyboard.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Enter the quantity: ");
    int quantity = keyboard.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Enter the price: ");
    double price = keyboard.nextDouble();
    cart.addToCart(item, price, quantity);
    System.out.print("Enter the name of the next item or Q to quit: ");
    String quit = keyboard.nextLine();
    char choice = quit.charAt(0);
    while((choice != 'Q' && choice != 'q') || quit.length() != 1) {
        quit = item;
        System.out.print("Enter the quantity: ");
        quantity = keyboard.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter the price: ");
        price = keyboard.nextDouble();
        cart.addToCart(item, price, quantity);
        System.out.print("Enter the name of the next item or Q to quit: ");
        quit = keyboard.nextLine();
        choice = quit.charAt(0);
    }           
    System.out.println(cart);
}
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Skipping nextLine() after using next(), nextInt() or other nextFoo() methods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/skipping-nextline-after-using-next-nextint-or-other-nextfoo-methods)

Comment: As the solutions in the duplicate question indicate, the simplest way to fix your code is to use `keyboard.nextLine()` with a corresponding parsing method for numerical user input: `quantity = Integer.parseInt(keyboard.nextLine());` and `price = Double.parseDouble(keyboard.nextLine());`. The problem is occurring because `Scanner.nextInt()` and `Scanner.nextDouble()` do not consume the last newline character in `System.in`.

Comment: Stupid title. `"string.java:658"` isn't a problem that needs a solution. It is a file/line number reference.

Answer (score 0):

The error is occuring at this line

```
char choice = quit.charAt(0);
```

This is due to the fact that when you call

```
double price = keyboard.nextDouble();
```

then `nextDouble` leaves the newline in the input stream. So when following is called

```
String quit = keyboard.nextLine();
```

then result of `nextLine` is empty string, results in the given error when you try to use `charAt` method.

**To resolve this error**, simply change following

```
String quit = keyboard.nextLine();
```

To

```
String quit = keyboard.next();
```

Hope this helps